# Angular $scope as one object literal or multiple $scope's

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have the following controller

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.username = 'World';

        $scope.sayHello = function () {
            $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
        };
}]);
```

is there any reason why i should not use object literals

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.viewModel = {
            greeting: '',
            username: 'World',
            sayHello: function(){
                this.greeting = 'Hello ' + this.username + '!';
            }
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use object literal rather than bind everything $scope.
Its manageable and good practice.

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var viewModel = {
        greeting: '',
        username: 'World'
    };

    viewModel.sayHello = function () {
        this.greeting = 'Hello ' + this.username + '!';
    };
    $scope.viewModel = viewModel;
}]);
```

Comment: Ah that is a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `this` instead of `$scope`.
By using the **Controller As** declaration in your views you will end up with a dot notation in your views as well.

Your controller code could then end up looking like the following:

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
    .controller('MyController', function () {
    var self = this;
    this.greeting = '';
    this.username = '';

    this.getName = function () {
        self.greeting = 'Hello ' + self.username + '!';
    };
}]);
```

Using the **Controller As** declaration in your view will result in the following:

```
<div data-ng-controller="UserController as user">
       Hello {{ user.username }}
</div>
```

So in this example you end up with less code, but you maintain the dot notation in your views.

Please note that the **Controller As** functionality is not available pre Angular 1.2.0

Comment: just to add to this, the ControllerAs syntax is the first step in every official video segment showing converting from an angular 1.x app to an angular2 app, so using ControllerAs will put you closer to being compatible out of the box, and is the preferred syntax for the internal angular team.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to add more code to your HTML. You will have to access a particular variable by using {{viewModel.username}}.

To avoid this you could also code like this

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var viewModel = {
            greeting: '',
            username: 'World',
            sayHello: function(){
                this.greeting = 'Hello ' + this.username + '!';
            }
        };
        angular.extend($scope, viewModel);
}]);
```

But I think the first method is more easy to read then this notation. But there is no major harm in using any one of the approaches.

Comment: I also think the first one is easier to read but that's probably just because of the example that i used. I use object literals a lot because its a nice way to organize your code. But i never really see it in angular coding examples

Comment: Most angularJs devs usually come from Javascript background. So I think they adapt the first way and thats why the docs contains code similar to example 1. But each individual has his own preference.